# Why does eventlistener 'Change' not trigger function on unchecking radio?

Tags: javascript, html

Based on wether a radiobutton is checked, I want to trigger a function which changes the `value` of my element with id `next-page`. This is my code:

```js
var uitschrijven_definitief = document.getElementById("uitschrijven");
var nextpage = document.getElementById("next-page");
  
  document.getElementById("uitschrijven").addEventListener("change", function() {
   if (uitschrijven_definitief.checked === true) {
    nextpage.value = "https://www.google.nl/";
   }  else {
    nextpage.value = "https://mywebsite.com";
   }
});
```

```html
<input id="next-page" type="hidden" name="next" value="https://mywebsite.com"/>

<input id="3-maanden" name="dbfield240" class="clear-datum" type="radio" value="3 maanden"><label for="3-maanden">3 maanden</label>
<input id="6-maanden" name="dbfield240" class="clear-datum" type="radio" value="6 maanden"><label for="6-maanden">6 maanden</label>
<input id="uitschrijven" name="dbfield240" class="clear-datum" type="radio" value="Uitgeschreven"><label for="uitschrijven">Uitschrijven</label>
```

So the thing is, changing the value of my input box with id `next-page` on selecting the radio with id`uitschrijven` works, but it doesn't change back to `https://mywebsite.com` after deselecting it. Does anyone know why and how to fix this so it does work?

Comment: The `change` event is only fired on select, so the `else` block never gets executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the event listener to all of the radio buttons. You can't just add it to the last one, expecting the first and second one to handle the event as well.

You should also compare the selected target's value to the value of the final radio button.

```js
e.target.value === 'Uitgeschreven'
```

This makes the function more generic, and less coupled to the existance of an element.

### Example

```js
var nextpage = document.getElementById('next-page');

// Add event listener to all radio buttons.
document.querySelectorAll('.clear-datum[name="dbfield240"]')
  .forEach(radio => radio.addEventListener('change', handleOnChange));

function handleOnChange(e) {
  if (e.target.value === 'Uitgeschreven') {
    nextpage.value = 'https://www.google.nl/';
  } else {
    nextpage.value = 'https://mywebsite.com';
  }
  console.log(nextpage.value); // Print the current new value...
}
```

```html
<input id="next-page" type="hidden" name="next" value="https://mywebsite.com" />

<input id="3-maanden" name="dbfield240" class="clear-datum" type="radio" value="3 maanden"><label for="3-maanden">3 maanden</label>
<input id="6-maanden" name="dbfield240" class="clear-datum" type="radio" value="6 maanden"><label for="6-maanden">6 maanden</label>
<input id="uitschrijven" name="dbfield240" class="clear-datum" type="radio" value="Uitgeschreven"><label for="uitschrijven">Uitschrijven</label>
```

Comment: Why argument `e` in the `handleOnChange` function

Comment: @Gad I just updated it. The `e` parameter is the `event` state that is passed to the listener function.

Comment: You can use `forEach` on a NodeList, so the spreading is not needed.

Comment: @korki The `e` is needed to figure out what was clicked.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! Do you know how this method is called? [... I want to read up on it.

Comment: @Sybrentjuh It's called [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). You can wrap an iterable using `[...iterable]` to cast it to a pseudo-array to give it `Array.prototype` methods. Traditionally `NodeList` types did not have the typical `Array` methods, but they have been slowly receiving support over the past few years.